# retrieve a single value from room entity using viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-mvvm

I am trying to implement favoriting feature in my application using room db. I am storing the data from an API call and present it using the ViewModel and MutableLiveData. The problem I going through is that I am unable to retrieve just the isFavorite flag from the entity using the viewModel.

The following is data class of my application

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "astronomyPictures"
)
data class AstronomyPOD(
    val copyright: String?,
    val date: String,
    val explanation: String,
    val hdurl: String?,
    val media_type: String,
    val service_version: String,
    @PrimaryKey
    val title: String,
    val url: String?,
    val isFavorite: Int? = null //THIS IS ONE ATTRIBUTE I AM TRYING TO RETRIEVE
    
)
```

When I store the API response in the room db I assign a default value to the isFavorite attribute using the below code:

```
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(astronomyPOD: AstronomyPOD)

    @Transaction
    suspend fun upsert(astronomyPOD: AstronomyPOD) {
        val pod = astronomyPOD.copy(isFavorite = astronomyPOD.isFavorite ?: 1)
        insert(pod)
    }
```

The below code tries to retrieve the isFavorite value from the database using the title as it is the primary key.

```
    @Query("SELECT isFavorite FROM astronomyPictures WHERE title = :title")
    suspend fun getIsFavoriteFromTitle(title: String) : Int
```

The database currently looks like the following:
[Database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWrtd.png)

I have tried using the MutableLiveData isFav and used .postValue() function as below:

```
private val _isFav = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    val isFav : LiveData<Int>
        get() = _isFav

isFav.postValue(podRepository.toggleFavorite(astronomyPOD.title, astronomyPOD.isFavorite ?: 0))
```

This is how I call the repository in the viewmodel

```
fun getIsFavorite(title: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        val favorite = podRepository.getIsFavoriteFromTitle(title)
        _isFav.postValue(favorite)
    }
```

I have tried to log the results but it always displays 0.
How can I do this?

Comment: isFav.postValue(podRepository.toggleFavorite(astronomyPOD.title, astronomyPOD.isFavorite ?: 0))
 where in viewmodel is this called in some coroutine scope?

Comment: The table names don't match ("astronomyPictures" != "entity").

Comment: any particular reason for set the default value to isFavorite?

Comment: Could you please add full function inside viewmodel where you get data from room db? where you put the log?  1.-You have to do any database related operation in background thread.  2.-You've write `astronomyPictures` name in query but in model class entity declaration you've written `entity`  3.-Please make sure the `title` you pass in `getIsFavoriteFromTitle` function argument is available in database record (here you can run this query direct in database for cross verification)

Comment: @Raghunandan yes I tried calling the isFav variable in the homeFragment using .observe

Comment: @dev.bmax I changed the entity name just for the question, I was supposed to update it

Comment: @HanifShaikh the reason I want to set isFavorite is so that I can toggle favorite like a switch and update UI components based on the value like the icons.

Comment: there is _fav and fav are you sure you are using the right livedata?

Comment: @Raghunandan yes I changed it a bit using a backing property for isFav